# How to use a Hash before defining it in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a Ruby script with a very long Hash with more than 300 associations.
The script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

Array_A = []
myHash = {
                "x1" => "2",
                "x2" => "0",
                "x3" => "1",
                .
                .
                .
                "X350" => "1"
                }

myHash.keys.each do |z|
    Array_A << "This is key " + z
end

puts myHash.values.join("|")                            
puts Array_A.join("|")
```

But since the Hash is very large, for reading purposes I'd like to put the Hash at the end of the script and the `each` loop and `puts` command first, something like this:

```
Array_A = []

myHash.keys.each do |z|
    Array_A << "This is key " + z
end

puts myHash.values.join("|")                            
puts Array_A.join("|") 

myHash = {
                "x1" => "2",
                "x2" => "0",
                "x3" => "1",
                .
                .
                .
                "X350" => "1"
                }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Personally, I'd put the Hash in another file in a situation like that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit weird, but this is basically what DATA is for. The catch is that it's a file containing the contents of the section after `__END__`, so you'll need to go from that to a hash. So something like:

```
Array_A = []

myHash = eval DATA.read    

myHash.keys.each do |z|
    Array_A << "This is key " + z
end

puts myHash.values.join("|")                            
puts Array_A.join("|") 

__END__
{ 
  "x1" => "2",
  "x2" => "0",
  "x3" => "1",
  …
  "X350" => "1"
}
```

Comment: Hello Chuck, thanks for the help. It works fine!. DATA works only for one thing? I mean, can I refer for example to more hashes below _END_ and call them from above?